# Do ADA Refactor/JARVIS Virus count as a portal capture for missions?

Tags: ingress

When doing an Ingress mission waypoint does a ADA Refactor/JARVIS Virus fulfill the "capture or upgrade portal" requirement?  Assuming the portal is changed to your faction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does count as a capture for missions.  I just did ADA Refactor on on a enlightened portal with level 8 resonators.

Comment: Just a note -- using refactor/virus on an enemy portal will NOT gain you any stats. You will not gain a portal capture, you will not gain a unique visit and you will not gain any AP.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my only experience with ADA refactor, I can say that Virus captures do not count towards portal capture. Thus using ADA/Jarvis for a "capture the portal" mission would not be a wise move.

Comment: Your answer isn't clear if you were in an active mission when you used the ADA refactor.  Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, your answer turned out to be wrong.

Comment: The virus works for missions, but does not count towards badge statistics.